# Cross Multiplication with Arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to find help on how to reproduce the following image. I don't have much for a minimal example except:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{3}{5}&=\dfrac{4.50}{x}\\
          3x&=5(4.50) &&\textcolor{blue}{\text{Set cross products equal}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Here is an image of what I want:

[image]

Can someone help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proposal. Normally one could get rid of the darker region at the intersection by dialing `transparency group`, but for some reason this makes here the arrows disappear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\tikzmark{f1}\dfrac{3}{5}&=\dfrac{4.50}{x}\tikzmark{f2}\\
          3x&=5(4.50) &&\textcolor{blue}{\text{Set cross products equal}}
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\begin{scope}[opacity=0.2]
\begin{scope}[blend mode=multiply]
\path let 
\p1=($([yshift=4mm,xshift=3mm]pic cs:f2)-([yshift=-2mm,xshift=-3mm]pic cs:f1)$),
\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
([yshift=-2mm,xshift=-3mm]pic cs:f1) -- ([yshift=4mm,xshift=3mm]pic cs:f2)
node[fill=blue,midway,sloped,single arrow,minimum height=\n1]{};
\path let 
\p1=($([yshift=4mm,xshift=-3mm]pic cs:f1)-([yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm]pic cs:f2)$),
\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
([yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm]pic cs:f2) -- ([yshift=4mm,xshift=-3mm]pic cs:f1)
node[fill=blue,midway,sloped,single arrow,minimum height=\n1,
shape border rotate=180]{};
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that is very good. Would placing the tikzmarks in denominators improve the picture? Let me look at this in the morning. Thank you. Again I would have never been able to come even close to this program. Way beyond my abilities.

Comment: @MathScholar In this case it would probably be easier to adjust the `yshift` and `xshift` values.

Comment: is it possible to put text near the arrow tips without touching the arrows and disrupting the picture?

Comment: Yes, just add nodes in the overlay picture. (I'm not really online now.)

Comment: I tried a few things but could not get it to work. I'd appreciate it if you show me later. No hurry, thanks Marmot

Comment: @MathScholar You could just add `\node[anchor=north east] at ([xshift=-3mm,yshift=7mm]pic cs:f1) {text 1};
\node[anchor=north west] at ([xshift=3mm,yshift=7mm]pic cs:f2) {text 2};` below the second `\end{scope}`. Of course, you may have to adjust the `xshift` and `yshift` to get what you want.

Comment: I got it to work and didn't need to adjust a thing! I posted an image above. Thanks Marmot